# Facing error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm am running springboot application in tomcat so getting the following error. It seems there are multiple slf4j. Not sure how to resolve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.69-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-9.0.69/webapps/mobius/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.18.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.69-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-9.0.69/webapps/mobius/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
28-Aug-2023 00:02:45.047 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
28-Aug-2023 00:02:45.048 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/application] startup failed due to previous errors
I have tried exclusions the dependency but not working -

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
                <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>

                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

The pom file uses a spring boot parent we created ourselves. Maybe that is where the exclusions need to take place?

Comment: Perhaps start by removing the slf4j jar (and possibly from your build dependencies) as that is already contained in logback-classic